# Diaog open callback function executes only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

My jQueryUI dialog open callback function executes only for the first time the dialog opens but I want it to work every time I open the dialog. Can anyone help?

```
$('<div><b><center>'+ text +'</center></b></div>').dialog({
    title: '<b>User(s) with a similar name</b>', 
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 'auto', 
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    open: function() { 
        $('#smartpaginate').smartpaginator({ 
            totalrecords: 3,
            recordsperpage: 2, 
            datacontainer: 'all-tabs', 
            dataelement: 'table',
            theme: 'green' 
        });
    },
    buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
            //alert($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The code in the callback executes a pagination plugin, [Jquery smart paginator](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-pagination-plugin-smart-paginator/).

Comment: Full html code please. Can't say solve your problem without got your html structure. You should not re-run smartpaginator again, just once in the first render (may be you got error from here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, this code snippet is not enough to understand your problem. See in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_LPO/qZfwA/2/) that the open callback function is always called.
I have just added a smartpaginate div and a button to control the dialog opening :

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title"><div id="smartpaginate"></div></div>
```

And a message to visualize that the call is performed :

```
$('#opener').after('<p>dialog open function triggered</p>');
```

Maybe you should have a look in your js console, and give us more context.